# error: declaration of 'operator<<' as non-function|

Tags: c++

I am having a really hard time with overloading the << operator.  I am working on a homework assignment where I can only modify certain portions of the code.  Before you ask, I AM stuck using a struct instead of a class.  Here are the portions of the affected code:

The calling function is:

```
/*
 * Write a CSV report listing each course and its enrollment.
 */
void generateReport (ostream& reportFile,
             int numCourses,
             Course* courses)
{
  for (int i = 0; i < numCourses; ++i)
    {
        //courses is an array of "Course" structs
        reportFile << courses[i] << endl;
    }
}
```

Here is the .h file:

```
#ifndef COURSE_H
#define COURSE_H

#include <iostream>
#include <string>


struct Course {
    std::string name;
    int maxEnrollment;
    int enrollment;

    Course();
    Course(std::string cName);

    std::ostream& operator << (ostream &out, const Course &c);
};

#endif
```

Here is the .cpp file:

```
#include "course.h"

using namespace std;


Course::Course()
{
    name = "";
    maxEnrollment = 0;
    enrollment = 0;
}

Course::Course(string cName)
{
    name = cName;
    maxEnrollment = 0;
    enrollment = 0;
}

// send course to file
ostream& Course::operator << (ostream &out, const Course &c)
{
    out << c.name << "," << c.enrollment << endl;
    return out;
}
```

Here is the error message I keep getting:

error: declaration of 'operator<<' as non-function|

I have been searching the internet for hours and tried lots of different approaches to solve this problem with no success.
Please help!!

I tried a couple of different methods to fix this based on advice.  Here are two methods I tried which did not work:
Method 1:

```
#ifndef COURSE_H
#define COURSE_H

#include <iostream>
#include <string>


struct Course {
    std::string name;
    int maxEnrollment;
    int enrollment;

    Course();
    Course(std::string cName);

};

//Moved this outside the struct
std::ostream& operator << (ostream &out, const Course &c);

#endif
```

Method 2 (also failed to change error):

```
#include "course.h"

using namespace std;


Course::Course()
{
    name = "";
    maxEnrollment = 0;
    enrollment = 0;
}

Course::Course(string cName)
{
    name = cName;
    maxEnrollment = 0;
    enrollment = 0;
}

std::ostream& operator << (ostream &out, const Course &c);


// send course to file
ostream& Course::operator << (ostream &out, const Course &c)
{
    out << c.name << "," << c.enrollment << endl;
    return out;
}
```

RE-EDIT--------------------------------------------------------
After some of the comments and help, here is my current code:

In the .h file:

```
#ifndef COURSE_H
#define COURSE_H

#include <iostream>
#include <string>


struct Course {
    std::string name;
    int maxEnrollment;
    int enrollment;

    Course();
    Course(std::string cName);

    std::ostream& operator << (std::ostream &out, const Course &c);
};

#endif
```

In the .cpp file:

```
#include "course.h"

using namespace std;

Course::Course()
{
    name = "";
    maxEnrollment = 0;
    enrollment = 0;
}

Course::Course(string cName)
{
    name = cName;
    maxEnrollment = 0;
    enrollment = 0;
}


// send course to file
ostream& operator << (ostream &out, const Course &c)
{
    out << c.name << "," << c.enrollment << endl;
    return out;
}
```

Comment: friend. in the struct

Answer (score 8):

**You forgot to include `<ostream>` and the namespace specifier `std::` in your argument, which leads into your error.**

Read on if you want to hear about your next error:

```
std::ostream& operator << (std::ostream &out, const Course &c);
```

This means that you define an operator which should work on a current instance of a `Course` as left hand side (`*this`), since it is defined as a member. This would lead into an operator that has one left hand side and two right hand sides, which isn't possible.

You need to define the operator as a non-member function, since the left hand side should be an `ostream&` and not `Course&`.

Comment: It is a struct, not a class.  Where should I define it?  I have tried moving the definition to the .cpp file and it doesn't help.

Comment: @LTDAN626: Doesn't matter. `structs` are `classes` with default `public` in C++.

Comment: A struct is just a class whose members/functions are public by default, nothing special. Same things you can do with a class you can do with a struct.

Comment: @LTDAN626: You didn't include `ostream` and forgot `std::` in your argument.

Comment: fixed this and removed declaration from struct.  Now I'm getting a host of other errors.  See above.

Comment: @LTDAN626: See [stardust's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/15734039/1139697). If you don't know the difference between member function and non-member function [get a book](http://tinyurl.com/so-cxxbooks)

Answer (score 4):

```
std::ostream& operator << (std::ostream &out, const Course &c);
```

should be

```
friend std::ostream& operator << (std::ostream &out, const Course &c);
```

And

```
std::ostream& Course::operator << (std::ostream &out, const Course &c)   // Not a member of Course
{
```

should be

```
std::ostream& operator << (std::ostream &out, const Course &c)
{
```

Since it is not a member of `Course`.

Comment: The `friend` is irrelevant. The real problem is that it needs to be a non-member function, which `friend` implies.

Comment: Same error remains.  Besides, I am using a struct not a class.  Members are public no matter what.

Comment: trying your fixes will repost in a moment

Comment: LOL I made this change and I got tons of errors.  Here is a sample:  I:\CS250\Assignments\Operator Oveloading\overloading\enrollment.cpp||In function 'void generateReport(std::ostream&, int, Course*)':|
I:\CS250\Assignments\Operator Oveloading\overloading\enrollment.cpp|67|error: no match for 'operator<<' in 'reportFile << *(courses + ((sizetype)(((unsigned int)i) * 12u)))'|
I:\CS250\Assignments\Operator Oveloading\overloading\enrollment.cpp|67|note: candidates are:|
c:\program files (x86)\codeblocks\mingw\bin\..\lib\gcc\mingw32\4.7.1\include\c++\ostream|106|note: std::basic_ostream ....

Comment: In that case I think you should keep the friend declaration. I was surprised it did work here. `friend std::ostream& operator << (ostream &out, const Course &c);` in the struct. I was actually googling to see if it is allowed to have non friend overloaded ostream operators.

Comment: should i put the declaration back into the struct?  I currently have it moved from the .h file to the .cpp file.

Comment: I moved the line:                                             ostream& operator << (ostream &out, const Course &c);back into the struct.  However now I am getting the error: ostream does not name a type.

Comment: add `using namespace std;` or use `std::ostream` in the file where you are getting the error.

Comment: gah.  now it says the function must take only one argument.

Comment: The symbol `ostream` is either visible in the OP namespace (the global one?), so no `std::` is needed, or not visible, so `std::` must be there at every `ostream` ocourence.

Comment: @Pubby I know this is rather silly, but when you say it should be a non-member function, you mean that it should be outside of the .h file?

Answer (score 1):

`std::ostream& operator << (ostream &out, const Course &c);` inside the `Course` declaration, must be declared as `friend`, otherwise it cannot take two parameters.

also, the fist parameter must be `std::ostream&` and not just `ostream&`

Comment: It doesn't have to be a friend as there are no private members in  the struct.

Comment: @BoPersson: Don't forget this is an *answer* to a specific *question*, where the function was declared INTO the class declaration block.  It `has to` be friend to stay there. OR it can be not friend, but must stay alone (and the code must be completely restructured). I jutt tried to be conservative respect to what the OP did.